# Selenium web scraping difficulties?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

New to coding and recently discovered Web Scraping! I found out that it would really help me with my marketing internship and also thought it would be good project to work on!

Essentially, I am trying to create a program to run on instagram that would help gather "influencers", their names, follower count, city, and if any of their posts have specific hashtags like "health", "fitness", etc. I did some research and found out about selenium and using web drivers so I started coding. Everything went ok at first, I could get the program to open a Safari browser, but now I am having trouble logging in.

This is the error I am receiving:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementNotVisibleException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6ec476894621> in <module>
      9 sleep(2)
     10 username_input = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
---> 11 username_input.send_keys("test_research")
     12 
     13 sleep(2)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
    478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
--> 479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    480 
    481     # RenderedWebElement Items

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementNotVisibleException: Message: An element command could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page.
```

I tripled checked the HTML and it seems like what I am using is the right name, but for some reason, my program can't find the username or password box and input the info. Any and all help would be appreciated. Below is my attempt code.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Safari()

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')

sleep(2)
username_input = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
username_input.send_keys("******")

sleep(2)
password_input = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password_input.send_keys("******")

login_button = browser.find.element_by_name('//
[@id="reactroot"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[4]')
login_button.click()
```

Below is the HTML for the username box

```
<label class="f0n8F "><span class="_9nyy2">Phone number, username, or email</span><input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value=""></label>
```

Below is the HTML for the password box

```
<label class="f0n8F "><span class="_9nyy2">Password</span><input aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="password" type="password" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value=""></label>
```

Also here is the login button

```
<div class="                    Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm    bkEs3                          CovQj                  jKUp7          DhRcB                                                    "><button class="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " disabled="" type="submit"><div class="                    Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                                                                                              ">Log In</div></button></div>
```

Comment: try using the chrome instance, i didnt find any issue to locate the username and password sections

Comment: Still go the same Message error in Chrome  :/

Comment: i dont find anything out of normal in your chuck of code. try using the xpath or the css to find the elements. ive used this     #logging into the account
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input').send_keys('*************')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input').send_keys('********')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button/div').click()

Comment: @VenuBhaskar Tried that and even implemented WebdriverWait element but i got an error with no message :\ I'm thinking there's something wrong with my computer, so I'm gonna code this program on a different Mac and see if it works. Thanks for the help!